# Getting API callback to pass outside of function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-geocoder

I can not get data to pass past line 72(I marked with a break line). Up to that point everything is passing great(data from Database is passing to "google-geocoder" and "geoPlace" object is coming through Callback in "data" param but when I try to access "data" outside of "geocoder" function "Data" becomes undefined.
I have tried .bind, setState, window., etc.. all with no luck.
I feel like it is a scope issue but not sure.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
// Feed
//     Tools
//     Listing
//     Location
//         FeedMap
//           MapLoader

import React from 'react';
import geocoder from 'google-geocoder';
import FeedMap from './feedMap.js';

var Location = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      petTrip: []
    }
   },

  getAllpetTripFromServer: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/travel'
    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data, "I am the data from line 17");
       self.setState({ petTrip: data })
     })
   },

  componentDidMount: function(){
     this.getAllpetTripFromServer();
   },

 //()
   render: function(){
     console.log(this.state.petTrip, 'I am the console log from line      28');
     return (
      <div>
           <AllpetTrip petTrip={this.state.petTrip}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

});


 var AllpetTrip = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
      // console.log(this.props.petTrip, "at map")
    var trips = this.props.petTrip.map(function(item){
      return <Geolocator start={item.startPoint}/>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        { trips }
      </div>
    )
   }
 });




var Geolocator = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
     var geo = geocoder ({
     key: 'AIzaSyC9Zst0uBpxGJ2P4LLv3IMATpN9Ppl4ImI'
      });
       geo.find(this.props.start, function(err, data){
       console.log(data, "this is the GeoPlace object")
        });
```

---

```
      return(
        <div>
        <FeedMap  geolocations = { data }/>
        </div>
    )
  }

});


 module.exports = Location;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to access the properties of component before receive these.

```
var AllpetTrip = React.createClass({
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.setState({
     petTrip: props.petTrip
    })
  },
  getInitialState(){
   return({
    petTrip: []
   })
  },
  render: function(){
      // console.log(this.props.petTrip, "at map")
    var trips = this.state.petTrip.map(function(item){
      return <Geolocator start={item.startPoint}/>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        { trips }
      </div>
    )
   }
 });
```

or use a condition on your code:

```
var AllpetTrip = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
      // console.log(this.props.petTrip, "at map")
    var trips = this.props.petTrip.length ? this.props.petTrip.map(function(item){
      return <Geolocator start={item.startPoint}/>
    }) : null

    return (
      <div>
        { trips }
      </div>
    )
   }
 });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look this over. That is not where I am having the problem, AllpetTrip is passing it's data fine. It is at the "Geolocator" component that I can not get data to pass to my React Map.  The geocoder function works and gives me 'data' in the callback, however it will not return/render another component which is the map itself, or pass the 'data' in the callback to another component.